# Command not found when starting github gollum on mac 10.7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I have tried to follow the installation instructions from:

[Github Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum)

I have a fresh lion install and installed xcode command line tools. Then I did the following:

```
homebrew < -- ran script from website
brew doctor
brew install git
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
rbenv install 1.9.3-p362
rbenv rehash
rbenv global 1.9.3-p362
gem install gollum

mkdir ~/gollum_test
cd ~/gollum_test
git init

gollum
```

I get **-bash: gollum: command not found**

I'm new to all the tools above, so I don't know what I've missed.

Answer (score 7):

Solved, I had to run

```
rbenv rehash
```

again!